# Read-only directory on Windows?

Tags: windows, permissions, cygwin, acl

Is it possible to create read only directory on windows so I can't create files/directories in it? I've denied all permissions for all users, set folder read-only and I can still create files and access that folder from cygwin or programmatically (Java). It effectively just denies accessing it from windows explorer and cmd.

Answer (score 0):

You can do following these steps to set permission

1. Right-click the folder > Properties
2. Security tab > Advanced
3. Click On change permission.
4. Select entry and click on edit button and you can add new entry for new user
5. If you want to restrict checked on deny check box whatever you want to restrict and then click ok
6. if you add new entry then you have also option to set allow deny option aur also full control option .
7. if you want to permission will apply on objects subfolders too then checked on be below box you will see then click ok

Hopefully, these steps may help you

Comment: No. With all deny permissions like here: [permission settings](https://s14.postimg.org/b73oomku9/Untitled.png) I can still access and create folder inside from cygwin.

Comment: Did you checked on "Apply these permissions to objects and containers within this container only" ?

Comment: I have this checkbox greyed out